# Module not found when importing <App/> outside src folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to convert my react app created with CRA to server rendering and following a tutorial I started to use the following configuration:

my-app/server/index.js:

```
import express from 'express';

import serverRenderer from './middleware/renderer';

const PORT = 3000;
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

router.use('^/$', serverRenderer);

router.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build'), { maxAge: '30d' }));

app.use(router);

app.listen(PORT, (error) => {
  if (error) {
    return console.log('something bad happened', error);
  }

  console.log('listening on ' + PORT + '...');
});
```

my-app/server/middleware/renderer.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';

// import our main App component
import App from '../../src/views/App';

const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

export default (req, res, next) => {
  // point to the html file created by CRA's build tool
  const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'build', 'index.html');

  fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', (err, htmlData) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('err', err);
      return res.status(404).end();
    }

    // render the app as a string
    const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />);

    // inject the rendered app into our html and send it
    return res.send(
      htmlData.replace('<div id="root"></div>', `<div id="root">${html}</div>`)
    );
  });
};
```

my-app/server/bootstrap.js:

```
require('ignore-styles');

require('@babel/register')({
  ignore: [/(node_modules)/],
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
});

require('./index');
```

I start the server with `node server/bootstrap.js`, and receive the following error message: `Error: Cannot find module '../constants/RouteEnum'`. This comes from the `import App` I do in the `renderer.js`. I reinforce that this module exists and is working (no problems at all if I just run `npm start`, the app is loaded in the browser without any errors), but for some reason, my server cannot interpret correctly from where it comes.

Any guesses of how to fix that?